# Where should one start if they want to go about identifying phytoplankton and dinoflagellates?

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature, marine-biology

I'm a first year university student and I really need help on how to identify and recognize the different organisms observed in my water samples. Are there any good references/tips on how to?